# Convergence of $1 +\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9} +\frac{1}{13}+\dots$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

This is probably incredibly simple, but we've just started the topic, and we've just gone over geometric series, p-series, and harmonic series. Its simple when the series is given explicitly in sigma-notation, but I struggle when they don't give you the form and just give you the first few numbers. The question exactly is:

Determine whether the following series converges or diverges. Give a reason for your answer.

$$1+\frac15+\frac19+\frac1{13}\dots$$

Any tips/hints/help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think your self-diagnosis is accurate: you want to master the skill of being given a series in this form and writing it as a series given by a formula. How would you describe, in words, the pattern of denominators in this series you're given?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The first thing that I noticed was that it was all very close to multiples of 5, but off by an increasing amount. (1/9 is close to 1/(10-1), 1/13 is 1/(15-2)...) For whatever reason, I didn't see that it was also one larger than multiples of 4, which is a lot easier to write explicitly as tilper showed in the answer below. I guess as I practice, I'll recognize these things more easily?

Comment: Absolutely—the more we practice, the better we get, just like anything!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The series you give looks like: $$\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac1{4n+1}$$

To see this, note that each of the denominators are $1$ larger than a multiple of $4$:  $5 = 4 + 1$, and $9 = 8 + 1$, and $13 = 12 + 1$.  Presumably this pattern continues.  Then we note that $4 = 4 \cdot 1$, and $8 = 4 \cdot 2$, and $12 = 4 \cdot 3$, and so on.  So the first few terms are really:

$$1 + \frac1{4 \cdot 1 + 1} + \frac1{4 \cdot 2 + 1} + \frac1{4 \cdot 3 + 1} + \cdots$$

Being able to identify this type of pattern is a skill that will come naturally with practice.  So I definitely recommend getting lots of practice!

Anyway, you can use the [Limit Comparison Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with the harmonic series to get the answer to the actual question.  Let me know if you require further guidance.

---

**EDIT:**  The way you originally thought about it can also work:
\begin{align*}
  1+\frac15+\frac19+\frac1{13}+\cdots &= 1+\frac1{5-0}+\frac1{10-1}+\frac1{15-2}+\cdots\\[0.3cm]&=1+\frac1{5\cdot 1-0}+\frac1{5\cdot2-1}+\frac1{5\cdot3-2}+\cdots\\[0.3cm]&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac1{5\cdot n-(n-1)}\\[0.3cm]&=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac1{4n+1}\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks for the answer tilper. For whatever reason, instead of recognizing that each term was one larger than a multiple of four, I saw this pattern:

1/9 is 1/(10-1), 1/13 is 1/(15-2), 1/17 is 1/(20-3). Interesting. I suppose as I practice, I will think simpler first, and that way I'll avoid skipping over simple solutions.

Once you have $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac1{4n+1}$ I can see that it is in the form $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \frac1{an+b}$ and this behaves like a harmonic series (diverging to infinity). Right?

Comment: @akot717, yes, that's exactly right.  In fact, "behaves like" is the exact term I use when I teach/tutor this type of thing in person.  I can see you're building an intuition for this, and that's great.  Also, re: the original way you were thinking of it - that was a bit more complicated but it can be made to work also.  See my edit to the post.

Comment: thanks for all the help and encouragement! Also thanks for the edit. All makes sense now. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

For all $n$, we have 
$$\frac{1}{4n+\color{red}1}\geq \frac{1}{4n+\color{red}n}=\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{n}.$$
Thus, using the Comparison Test, the series $$\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{13}+\cdots$$ is divergent since the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(\frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{n})$ is divergent. Since adding a finite number of terms in a divergent series does not affect divergence, the given series
 $$1+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{13}+\cdots$$ is also divergent.

Comment: This is what I was thinking, even when I didn't recognize that it was $\frac1{4n+1}$. I thought, this is close to $\frac1{5n}$, and that is clearly divergent, so this should be divergent too since the sum of the corresponding terms are greater than the terms in $\frac1{5n}$.

Answer (score 4):

You could also observe that

$$1 +\frac{1}{5}+\frac{1}{9}\cdots \geq 1 + \frac{1}{5}\left (1 +\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3} +\cdots\right)$$
The term inside brackets is the harmonic series which....

Answer (score 2):

The series can be written as :
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{4n+1}$$

The integral test is the simplest in this case. The series is a lot like the harmonic series, so one might think that integral test can be used.

Compute the integral:
$$\int\frac{1}{4x+1}dx=\frac{\ln(4x+1)}{4}+C$$

Then compute the improper integral:
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{4x+1}dx=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln(4n+1)}{4}-\frac{\ln5}{4}$$
Clearly, the integral is divergent. Hence, the series is also divergent.

Comment: We haven't learned the integral test, and I'm limited to explaining in terms of geometric, p-series, or harmonic series properties. But thanks for the explanation!